# PassportJS and Facebook Opengraph api version 2.0 Error

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, passport.js, passport-facebook

I just started using the passport library recently and am a total noob. However, when I'm using my newly created facebook app to login I get the following error:

500 FacebookGraphAPIError: (#12) username is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher

```
at /app/node_modules/passport-facebook/lib/strategy.js:167:21
at passBackControl (/app/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:124:9)
at IncomingMessage. (/app/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:929:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

A bit of research shows me that facebook's open graph api no longer supports the "username" field. However it looks like the passport library is not supporting version 2.

Answer (score 1):

The current latest version of the Facebook Graph API is v2.2. You can fix passport-facebook (it use v1.0) by overriding options :

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

    clientID        : 'XXX',
    clientSecret    : 'XXX',
    callbackURL     : 'XXX',
    authorizationURL: 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth',
    tokenURL: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/oauth/access_token',
    profileURL: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me'

},
```